# proper way to return a large object or indicate that it is not found

Tags: c++, c++17

What is the idiomatic C++ way of doing this?
I have a method which looks like this:

```
LargeObject& lookupLargeObject(int id) {
  return largeObjects[id];
}
```

This is wrong, because if you call this with a non-existent id it will create a new instance of large object and put it into the container.  I don't want that.  I don't want to throw an exception either.  I want the return value to signal that object wasn't found (as it is a more or less normal situation).
So my options are either a pointer or an optional.  Pointer I understand and like, but it feels like C++ doesn't want to me use pointers any more.
So on to optionals. I will return an optional and then the caller looks like this:

```
std::optional<LargeObject> oresult = lookupLargeObject(42);
LargeObject result;
if (oresult) {
  result = *oresult;
} else {
  // deal with it
}
```

Is this correct?  It feels kind of crappy because it seems that I'm creating 2 copies of the LargeObject here? Once when returning the optional and once when extracting it from optional into result.  Gotta be a better way?

Comment: Why do you need the `result` variable? Why can't you just use `*oresult` within one branch?

Comment: e.g. for what @Brian might be suggesting: https://wandbox.org/permlink/XWFCLK4Jv2Ilvs2k

Comment: @Brian shake the words around a bit and you've got yourself an answer :)

Comment: Raw pointers continue to be a correct and valid choice for when you have no ownership of something and the thing might be null.

Comment: Is there any reason why you default-construct the extra `LargeObject`? Just do `auto const oresult = lookupLargeObject(42); if (oresult.has_value()) { /* use *oresult /* }`

Comment: @ChristianHackl yeah default-construct is just a silly mistake from inexperience.  But that's exactly the question -- how do I get my large object out of optional w/o making copies?  I guess I'm basically complaining that std::optional doesn't support references?

Comment: @MK.: I'm afraid the question is too broad. There are dozens of things you can do. Use smart pointers. Add an extra `exists()` member function, require clients to call it and `assert` if the key is not found. Return an iterator. Invert the control flow and add a member function which takes a generic function object or a `std::function` to operate on the element if it is found. Or use one of the suggested solutions in the answers.

Comment: `if (std::optional<LargeObject> oresult = lookupLargeObject(42)) { LargeObject& result = *oresult; /*use result*/ } else { /*deal with it*/ }`

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't want to return a pointer, but also don't want to throw an exception, and you presumably want reference semantics, the easiest thing to do is to return a `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<LargeObject>>`.

The code would look like this:

```
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<LargeObject>> lookupLargeObject(int id) {
    auto iter = largeObjects.find(id);
    if (iter == largeObjects.end()) {
        return std::nullopt;
    } else {
        return std::ref(iter->second);
    }
}
```

With C++17 you can even declare the `iter` variable inside the `if`-condition.

Calling the lookup function and using the reference then looks like this (here with variable declaration inside `if`-condition):

```
if (auto const lookup_result = lookupLargeObject(42); lookup_result) {
   auto& large_object = lookup_result.value().get();
   // do something with large_obj
} else {
  // deal with it
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that `operator->` doesn't work as it would in `boost::optional<T&>` with `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.

Comment: `if (auto const lookup_result = lookupLargeObject(42); lookup_result) { ...` is a longer, C++17-only way of saying `if (auto const lookup_result = lookupLargeObject(42)) { ...`, which works with any version of C++ (`auto` semantics excepted).

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches that do not require use of pointers - using a sentinel object, and receiving a reference, instead of returning it.

The first approach relies on designating a special instance of `LargeObject` an "invalid" one - say, by making a member function called `isValid`, and returning `false` for that object. `lookupLargeObject` would return that object to indicate that the real object was not found:

```
LargeObject& lookupLargeObject(int id) {
    if (largeObjects.find(id) == largeObjects.end()) {
        static LargeObject notFound(false);
        return notFound;
    }
    return largeObjects[id];
}
```

The second approach passes a reference, rather than receiving it back:

```
bool lookupLargeObject(int id, LargeObject& res) {
    if (largeObjects.find(id) == largeObjects.end()) {
        return false;
    }
    res = largeObjects[id];
    return true;
}
```

Comment: let's say sentinel is not an option because of my aesthetic preferences (and because I don't control LargeObject).  Isn't the reference passing approach still making a copy though?  I don't want copies...

Comment: @MK. Yes, unfortunately, the second approach does make a copy. If you do not control `LargeObject`, you should still be able to derive from it, making a subclass that can be valid or invalid. In case your aesthetic preferences change some day, an `InvalidLargeObject` subclass can be returned, because you are returning by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If default constructed `LargeObject` is unwanted from `lookupLargeObject`, regardless of whether it is expensive or it does not make semantic sense, you can use the `std:map::at` member function.

```
LargeObject& lookupLargeObject(int id) {
  return largeObjects.at(id);
}
```

---

If you are willing to  live with use of `if-else` blocks of code in the calling function, I would change the return type of the function to `LargeObject*`.

```
LargeObject* lookupLargeObject(int id) {
  auto it = largeObjects.find(id);
  if ( it == largeObjects.end() )
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
  return &(it->second);
}
```

Then, client code can be:

```
LargeObject* result = lookupLargeObject(42);
if (result) {
  // Use result
} else {
  // deal with it
}
```

Comment: Shorter version: `return largeObjects.at(id);`

Comment: I don't want exceptions though.

Comment: If you don't want exceptions, every client function has to check the return value for the validity of the returned object. You won't be able to avoid `if-else` code in every client function. If that's an acceptable solution, then use of `std::map::at` is definitely the not right solution.